# Is Order.asc(<String>) in Hibernate and "compareTo" in Comparable interface behave same?

Tags: java, hibernate, comparator

I use Hibernate to retrieve set of objects from data base and use Order.asc(studentName) to keep the ascending order.
I use Comparator to sort a object list manually, as below.

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Student>
   {
        public int compare(Student z1, Student z2)
            {
                 return z1.getName().compareTo(z2.getName());
            }
   }

Collections.sort(studentList, new NameComparator());
```

But the order of returned lists are not same in these two cases.

The first line is sorted with Hibernate, the second line is sorted with `NameComparator`

`aaa3, aaa4, bbb5, BBB7, bbb8, BBB8`

`aaa3, BBB7, BBB8, aaa4, bbb5, bbb8`

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The database probably uses a specific collation to sort (where, for example the order of [a, E, i, é, A] would be [A, a, E, é, i] whereas your pure lexicographic comparator would sort them as [A, E, a, i, é].

Comment: Please, add a simple example with two sorted lists.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes that must be the reason.

Comment: @v.ladynev Sorted with hibernate [aaa3,aaa4,bbb5,BBB7,bbb8,BBB8].Sorted with compareT [aaa3,BBB7,BBB8,aaa4,bbb5,bbb8]

Comment: @shamikaDharmasiri Is it a really valid example, because of it looks strange?

Comment: @v.ladynev But these are the results I am getting.I checked with "compareTo" ignoring the case,Then I get the same results as in Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Order.asc(studentName)`, then your data is sorted in the database. The `NameComparator` however sorts the data in your Java application. These two systems are unlikely to use the same sorting for strings.

Most databases use a case insensitive sorting while Java's `compareTo` is case sensitive. Furthermore, most databases have sophisticated sorting mechanisms for accents (the accented letter *à* will be close to the letter "a" in sorting), whitespace, hyphens, digits etc. that differ considerably from Java's default sorting. Finally, language and region settings affect the sorting order.

Even though the sorting can be configured in the database and implemented differently in Java, it is difficult to come up with matching behavior. You're better off either sorting everything in the database or everything in Java. The former option is to be preferred for big amounts of data.